# How to convert this Jquery Ajax to Pure Javascript Fetch?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna convert this snippet from Jquery Ajax to Fetch Pure Javascript. Can help me please?

I tried this before, but my code doesn't work as it should. I even asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73672340/error-converting-ajax-jquery-to-fetch-async-pure-javascript).

That's why I would like you to help me to convert it from zero, I could not.

```
ajaxCall = $.ajax({
  url: "data.php",
  dataType: "json",
  cache: false,
  type: "POST",
  data: "ajax=1&do=check&lista=" + encodeURIComponent(leray[chenille]),
  success: function (oreen) {
    switch (oreen.enviando) {
      case -1:
        chenille++;
        $("#div1").append(oreen.cat + "<br />");
        updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
        tvmit_wrongUp();
        break;

      case 1:
        chenille++;
        $("#div1").append(oreen.dog + "<br />");
        updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
        tvmit_wrongUp();
        break;

      case 2:
        chenille++;
        $("#div2").append(oreen.sky + "<br />");
        nieva++;
        updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
        tvmit_dieUp();
        break;

      case 3:
        chenille++;
        $("#div3").append(oreen.water + "<br />");
        tvmit_liveUp();
        updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
        break;
    }

    OKTY(leray, chenille, aarsh, nieva);
  }
});
return true;
```

Comment: Please include the attempt to convert it to vanilla JS in **this** question. One thing I already notice, you have a function called `ola` in your vanilla version, but it isn't getting called anywhere.  Could you also please explain **why** you need this converted? Are you moving away from jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with this.

1. URL is first option in the `fetch` method.
2. `cache: false` equivalent in fetch is `cache: 'no-cache'`
3. `type: POST` equivalent in fetch is `method: 'POST'`
4. You can add `data` as query in the URL
5. To convert data to `JSON` after getting the `response`, then execute `reponse.json()`

Lastly, you need to execute this in an `async` function, so you can `await`, or instead use `then` syntax.

```
try {
    const response = await fetch(`data.php?ajax=1&do=check&lista=${encodeURIComponent(leray[chenille])}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      cache: 'no-cache'
    })

    const oreen = await response.json();

    switch (oreen.enviando) {
          case -1:
            chenille++;
            $("#div1").append(oreen.cat + "<br />");
            updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
            tvmit_wrongUp();
            break;

          case 1:
            chenille++;
            $("#div1").append(oreen.dog + "<br />");
            updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
            tvmit_wrongUp();
            break;

          case 2:
            chenille++;
            $("#div2").append(oreen.sky + "<br />");
            nieva++;
            updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
            tvmit_dieUp();
            break;

          case 3:
            chenille++;
            $("#div3").append(oreen.water + "<br />");
            tvmit_liveUp();
            updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
            break;
        }

        OKTY(leray, chenille, aarsh, nieva);
    }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
```

Comment: and the results dont show on the divs :(

Comment: Does the network panel show the request and return the expected result?

Comment: EDIT: Just added `await` in line `const oreen = response.json();` and final result: `const oreen = await response.json();`